# Does HIV erase the immune memory?

Tags: immunology, hiv

It’s said that HIV selectively infects and kills CD4+ T cells, which disables the adaptive immunity because both CD8+ T cells and B cells need CD4+ T cells to activate them. However, once activated, memory B cells and CD8+ T cells can function independently of CD4+ T cell. Does that mean HIV+ people still retain immunity against previously encountered or vaccinated infections even at advanced disease stage?

Cited from:

> As the affinity of surface Ig from memory B cells is increased, their
> requirements for reactivation are lower than for naïve B cells: memory
> B cells may thus be recalled by lower amounts of antigen and without
> CD4+ T cell help.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9781416036111500064

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology! It would be helpful to link to/cite sources for your information.

Comment: Here: As the affinity of surface Ig from memory B cells is increased, their requirements for reactivation are lower than for naïve B cells: memory B cells may thus be recalled by lower amounts of antigen and without CD4+ T cell help. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9781416036111500064

Comment: Please edit your link into your question - that way it is more likely to be read, and more likely to persist as comments can and do get deleted occasionally.